# What is the longest URI that Salesforce will accept through the REST API?

Tags: rest, limits, url

### The Background

I was handed a task to populate a developer sandbox with a limited set of data from our production org to allow another dev team to be able to test integration with a third party (with respect to Salesforce) internally developed tool.

I settled on using a connected app and the [JWT Bearer OAuth flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5). That works just fine, so now I just need to write queries for a whole bunch of fields.

...and that's where I ran into issues.

Trying to query all of the fields on my org's `Account` object (239 fields total), with the URI looking like

```
// Multiple fields in a REST query are still comma separated.
// When URL-encoded, commas become %2C
https://<pod>.salesforce.com/services/data/v40.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id%2C+Name+<a bunch of other fields>+LIMIT+200
```

Salesforce gives me

> System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]

I thought that might be due to the URI being too long (4694 characters is a rather long URL in my book), but it ended up being the inclusion of a field in the query from a managed package that we're no longer using.

### The Question

That made me curious though, just what *is* the maximum length of URI that Salesforce will accept?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### +edit 2020-10-25:

Looks like there's some [concrete documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm) as of API v49.0 (Summer '20). The documented limit is 16,384 bytes.

The recommendation is to limit the URI to 2000 bytes, and headers to 8000 bytes.

#### +edit 2019-6-26:

Re-ran my code here, and came up with a limit of 16057. Looks like this number might vary from release to release, between pods, or perhaps some other criteria I am unaware of.

#### Original answer

Through trial and error, I was able to determine that Salesforce's limit on the URI length is 16,384 bytes (16,088 characters was my original finding).

Beyond that, Salesforce begins returning

> System.HttpResponse[Status=Request Header Fields Too Large, StatusCode=431]

At 16,410 characters long, Salesforce returns

> System.HttpResponse[Status=URI Too Long, StatusCode=414]

And finally, once the URI hits 32,435 characters, Salesforce croaks and we get the following exception

> System.CalloutException: Unexpected end of file from server

This was determined with the following anonymous apex

```java
// Setting up things for the JWT OAuth flow
// My connected app is set for admins selecting who is pre-authorized
String iss = '<client key of connected app>';
String aud = 'https://test.salesforce.com';
String sub = '<username for sandbox>';

Auth.JWT jwt = new Auth.JWT();
jwt.setAud(aud);
jwt.setIss(iss);
jwt.setSub(sub);

// 'Sandbox_Data_Populator' is the unique name of a self-signed certificate stored 
//   in Salesforce.
// This same cert is used as the digital signature for my connected app
Auth.JWS jws = new Auth.JWS(jwt, 'Sandbox_Data_Populator');

String tokenEndpoint = 'https://cs52.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';
Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange bearer = new Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange(tokenEndpoint, jws);
String accessToken = bearer.getAccessToken();

// Time to build the REST request OF DOOM!
// I have an Apex webservice whose URI is /services/apexrest/recordType
String endpt = '/recordType?s=';

// Start making the value to place in the query string
String qs = 'repeat';
// make it nice and long
endpt += qs.repeat(2725);
// and add some fine grain control
endpt += 'a'.repeat(1);

// Make the callout
// In this case, I'm calling out to the same org that I'm running this anonymous apex in
req.setEndpoint('https://cs52.salesforce.com/services/apexrest' + endpt);
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
req.setMethod('GET');
res = httpObj.send(req);
```

The precise values at which Salesforce returns the different HTTP codes and exception were determined by tuning `qs.repeat(2725);` using a binary-ish search approach.

I started at `qs.repeat(5000);`, went down to `qs.repeat(2500);`, up to `qs.repeat(2750);`, etc... until I found the coarse limit, then I adjusted `'a'.repeat(1);` (only need to go from 0 to 5) to find the exact limit.

Keep in mind that this limit appears to be for the entire URI. If you're using a longer URI, like say "https://my.custom.domain.salesforce.com", that'll eat up a few more characters than my "https://cs52.salesforce.com" does.

We can have up to 800 custom fields (or even more if you have managed packages installed) at a maximum of 60 characters each (40 for field label + `__c` + 15 for namespace + `__`), so it is possible to hit this limit if you attempt to query *all* fields on an object through the REST API...but that's not something most people will need to worry about.

Comment: You can actually have more than 800 custom fields when you include managed packages, since installed package fields don't count against org limits.

Comment: Maybe this used to be the limit in 2017. But today I found the URI limit to be closer to 10k characters (didn't experiment extensively though).

Comment: @SamKamensky You should be able to fairly easily adapt my code here and try out my procedure for yourself. The hardest part would be getting the JWT flow to work (which I believe requires you to use another OAuth flow to authorize just one user (doesn't have to be the same as the user you end up using in the JWT flow)). I set it up again myself, and found that the limit is a bit lower now (16057 now vs 16088 then).

Comment: @DerekF Hm, I'm using the simple_salesforce python library which harnesses the python requests library to make the http requests to the REST bulk api. I'm not sure why that would cause Salesforce errors to return a URI too long error at different URI lengths... (maybe the bulk api has different limits...?)