# Insert a new record with multiple fields Error 431 HTTP

Tags: error, fields, record, execute-anonymous

I am trying to insert a new records in my custom object Monitor__c with too many fields, when I execute my code in an anonymous window in the developer console, It delivers the following error:

Response to EXEC was : Bad Message 431
reason: Request Header Fields Too Large

This is because I am using many fields in the HEADER, How can I insert many fields in the BODY??? I am newby, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This is a similar problem to a question asked a few hours ago: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289351/error-while-adding-code-comments/ tl;dr: Your anonymous code is being sent to Salesforce as part of a query string, and you can't change that. The amount of code you've provided, however, shouldn't be enough to get you that particular error message though.

Comment: There's always a balance to be struck between providing too much code and providing not enough. In this case, I think we do need to see the entire contents of your execute anonymous window to be able to offer any specific help. Telling us more about your overall goal and the SObjects involved (and the relationships between them) will probably help. You can [edit] your question to include additional information.