# ERROR_HTTP_414 - <h1>Bad Message 414</h1><pre>reason: URI Too Long</pre> on VS Code

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, httprequest, scratch-org, vs-code, sfdx-plugin

I am trying to push the code to my scratch org through VS Code using following command - `sfdx force:source:push --json --loglevel fatal`
But getting following error on VS Code.

> ERROR_HTTP_414" - "Bad Message 414 reason: URI Too Long

Since this is happening at backend using push SFDX command, not able to see the request URI.

Is there any limitation on the content to be pushed through SFDX push commmad.

Comment: This is a similar error to the one I [encountered when using anonymous apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/195449/what-is-the-longest-uri-that-salesforce-will-accept-through-the-rest-api). A complete shot in the dark, but it may be that your project is too big (trying to push too many files). A packet capture/analyzer like Wireshark might help you debug this further.

Comment: Thank you @DerekF, will try to use Wireshark to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue. After using `sfdx force:source:push --loglevel trace` we found an absurdly long query in `User/.sfdx/sfdx.log`:

`"request: {\"method\":\"GET\",\"url\":\"https://my-scratch-1234.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v55.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT%20MemberType%2C%20MemberName%2C%20IsNameObsolete%20FROM%20SourceMember%20WHERE%20MemberName%20IN%20('MyCustomMtd.O1'%MyCustomMtd.O10'%2C` ... and continuing to form an extremely long list of Custom Metadata record names. Turns out the org had these Custom Metadata records, while the current git branch didn't have them anymore and sfdx was probably trying to compute a list of changes, but it was doing it in an way that doesn't scale to large amounts of data.

As a workaround we added the following to `.forceignore`:

`**/MyCustomMtd.*`

After that the push worked. For different cases the particular reasons may be different, but the problematic URI probably can be located in the log.